# Virtualhost and window host for different port

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, virtualhost, host

I am running two xampp on my window 7. One is with `php5.6` and other one is with `php7.2`. Port number for `php7` xampp is changed to `7777` as per the [article](http://webdevzoom.com/install-run-multiple-xampp-windows/) and it's working fine. I am able to run my project. Now the problem is I try to create virtual host to run my laravel site which is not working. I getting

> Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.

Here is my Vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:7777>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    ServerName localhost

    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride all
       Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:7777>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/test_web/public/"
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias test.com

    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/test_web/public/">
      Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
       #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

       Require local
       # if you want access from other pc's on your local network
       #Require ip 192.168.1
       # Only if you want the world to see your site
       #Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and this my host file

```
127.0.0.1:7777  test.com
::7777      test.com
```

I tried many combinations such as `127.0.0.1:7777` with `::7777`, `::1`, `::77`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Host names map on to IP addresses, not ports.

**The hosts file should not contain port numbers.**

`127.0.0.1:7777` should be `127.0.0.1` (the IPv4 loopback address)

`::7777` should be `::1` (the IPv6 loopback address).

**The port should be specified in the URL** when you are accessing a non-default port (i.e. 80 for HTTP or 443 for HTTPS).

e.g. `http://test.com:7777/`

Comment: Ok, but when I try `127.0.0.1` same error I get, but when I place `127.0.0.1:7777` it redirect me to default xampp dashboard.

Comment: @KapilSharma — The first virtual name host is the default and has `C:/xampp/htdocs/` as the document root. I would expect it to direct you to the default xampp dashboard.